Group Voice chat application
I am building a project that features group voice chat, allowing a group of people to audio chat with each other in real-time. I am using the MERN stack for development and using Socket.IO on the server side and socket.io-client on the client side to establish connections between sockets. I am also using Simple Peer to transmit real-time audio between users, but I am having trouble implementing the logic.
I tried all the possible ways I show on YouTube but I am not able to transmit audio.Can anyone help me with this?
